# Export to xls or cvs details of sales report in Opencart 3.0.2.0 admin

Tags: php, html, export-to-csv, export-to-excel, opencart-3

I just created a site with Opencart 3.0.2.0, but I can't export the details of the sales report with complete details like:

- Order ID
- Customer name
- Product code
- Product description
- Product quantity
- and The total price

Can anyone help me make it with coding or extensions to be able to export it into the xls or csv file format in the admin dashboard, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try [exporting the needed sales details](https://www.opencartmanager.com/useful-articles/opencart-order-managemement/how-to-export-opencart-orders/) with Store Manager, there are 2 available options for export: one in the grid for exporting customer-related and general order data and the other one in the grid for ordered products' details. you can also try it for free for two weeks.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question, apologizing for my delay in replying. In a month ago I tried coding to export the order report and get a lot of errors. Finally I bought a plugin and fix the problem :). Once again, thank you.